# Is the derivative of a function in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ a 2-adic number?

Tags: calculus, p-adic-number-theory

Looking for the flaw in the claim which [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384844/) asks about, one candidate is that the derivative of a function in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ is not necessarily itself in $\mathbb{Q}_2$.  Is it?

$\mathbb{Q}_2$ is the 2-adic numbers.

Specifically, if $f$ is a function $f:\mathbb{Q}_2\to\mathbb{Q}_2$

Then is $\displaystyle\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}_2$ for all such $f$ ?

I guess I'm asking whether $\displaystyle\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ also satisfies $\displaystyle\frac{df(x)}{dx}:\mathbb{Q}_2\to\mathbb{Q}_2$

Comment: Define "derivative of a function in $\mathbb{Q}_2$", please. Usually, a derivative is defined as a limit, and limits of sequences in complete metric spaces tend to belong to those spaces.

Comment: What Professor Vector is trying to ask you is: What does $\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x}$ mean to you?

Comment: I wasn't trying, I asked in plain text: what is the definition of "derivative", here?

Comment: @Arthur Let me answer what I think you're getting at... I'm aware that neighbouring points in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ are separated by large powers of $2$ rather than infinitessimals and therefore calculus has the potential to look completely different. However I naively hope I can use my regular calculus rules and the derivative will sit in $\mathbb{Q}_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the definition:
Let $f \colon \mathbb Q_2 \to \mathbb Q_2$ be a function.  Let $a \in \mathbb Q_2$ be a point.  We say $f$ is differentiable at $a$, and its derivative is $b$ iff
$$
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = b
$$
where the limit is done with the metric of $\mathbb Q_2$ and the quotient and difference are done with the operations of $\mathbb Q_2$.

If that is your definition, then (as in the real case) not every function is differentiable, but if a function is differentiable at some point, then the derivative indeed belongs to $\mathbb Q_2$.

**left to you:**

(1) Is $f(x) = x^2$ differentiable and $f'(x) = 2x$  ??

(2) Investigate differentiability of $\frac{1}{x}$.

(3) After you understand these, make a definition of "topological field" and try it there.

Comment: I'm thinking $2^{\nu_2(x)}$ has derivative zero everywhere except $x=0$, so $\frac{d}{dx}(3x+5\cdot2^{v_2(x)}) = 3$ for $x \ne 0$.

Comment: Ok having scratched my head for a good long while I think I need to take the $\displaystyle\lim_{\lvert x-a\rvert_2\to 0}$ of $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{\lvert x-a\rvert_2}$ is that correct?

Comment: No, you cannot combine 2-adics (like ${f(x)-f(a)}$) and reals (like ${\lvert x-a\rvert_2}$) in the same calculation.  You must use $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ as I wrote.  But you are correct that $x \to a$ is the same as ${\lvert x-a\rvert_2\to 0}$.

Comment: Not being down on your answer because it's a very helpful answer but I think it's missing something like; since $b$ is a limit point in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ with respect to $\lvert\cdot\rvert_2$, and $\mathbb{Q}_2$ is a complete space with respect to $\lvert\cdot\rvert_2$, it follows $b\in\mathbb{Q}_2$ and then I can accept.